# Is there an explanation for what happened to the Great Underground Empire in the Zork Trilogy?

Tags: video-games, zork

In the text only games known as the Zork series, you explored the ruins of what was once the Great Underground Empire.  I never found anything in game or otherwise that tried to explain what had happened to the Empire, and I was wondering if anyone knew of any explanation?

Citations from in-game material would be best, but anything with a relatively authoritative slant will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game [*Zork Zero*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork_Zero) covers the reasons behind fall of the Great Underground Empire.

> Lord Dimwit Flathead the Excessive certainly earned his nickname. Never one to do things on a small scale, when Dimwit decided in 789 GUE to have a statue erected in his honor, it had to be the largest statue ever. This angered a local resident of Fublio Valley (where the statue was built), Megaboz the Magnificent, who cast a deadly curse over Dimwit, the royal family, and the entire Empire before disappearing. The king's conjurers employed their most powerful magic in an effort to counteract the curse, but they were unable to save Dimwit and his eleven siblings; they only managed to delay the kingdom's destruction temporarily.

The fall begins as part of the game's prelude, occurs during the game, and the game ends

> immediately prior to the original *Zork*.

Comment: I just noticed that I never accepted this. :)